# How to set a schema in `node_modules` as a `$schema`

Tags: json, npm, uri, jsonschema

I'm creating an npm package which contains a schema file, **`set.schema.json`**. I'm wondering how I can set this as the `$schema` of a JSON file in another project with this package installed as a dependency. I'm mainly using the schema for IDE suggestions, rather than validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema does not specify a way to do this.

Any way you want to do this needs to be supported by the IDE in question.